# Notification on thread destroy

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, callback, notifications

Is it possible to get notified if a thread had been destroyed? I've already seen such question here:
[Notification when a thread is destroyed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513040/notification-when-a-thread-is-destroyed)

The answer was: **DLL_THREAD_DETACH**, but it won't get called in case of **TerminateThread**.
So, my question is that, is it possible to detect even the termination? I don't want to prevent it, just get a notification if any of my threads got destroyed. I don't necessarily want to use DllMain, any solution would be great!

I'm working in a DLL, which get's injected into my main application, so I can't use WaitForSingleObject, since it suspends the main executable.

Thank you for each answer.

*(P.s.: Just for understanding, my dll works the following way: Main application Loads the dll, on DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, I open up some threads.)*

Edit:
I forgot, I'm using windows & Visual Studio 2013.

Edit 2:
I came to that Disabling thread library calls, is useless. I mean it doesn't work the way I thought :) */I deleted that part, so it won't mislead anyone/*

Comment: but DisableThreadLibraryCalls() disables the DLL_THREAD_ATTACH and DLL_THREAD_DETACH notifications. So, you will never see DLL_THREAD_DETACH.

Comment: Even if I enable them, it will not call, so I don't need it anymore. Or am I wrong?

Comment: This requirement really does not make any sense. If your DLL starts a thread, and someone externally kills that thread, there is nothing you can do about that, the thread is gone. The only way to detect that is to monitor the thread being killed. But then what's to stop the attacker from killing the monitor, too? You will have to resort to either using thread heartbeats and detect when the heartbeats stop, or else hook every occurance of `TerminateThread()` in every process so you can check if one of your DLL's thread IDs is being targeted. I don't see any other way around this.

Comment: Creating threads in `DllMain` is almost guaranteed to deadlock, sooner or later. Read [Dynamic-Link Library Best Practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn633971.aspx) if you want to find out why.

Comment: @IInspectable: actually, that article appears to be remarkably vague on why or under what circumstances creating threads might be a problem.  All it says on the subject (that I can find) is "Creating a thread can work if you do not synchronize with other threads, but it is risky."

Comment: @Harry *"You cannot call any function in DllMain that directly or indirectly tries to acquire the loader lock."* Creating a thread is a potential candidate.

Comment: @IInspectable: I don't see any reason for CreateThread to attempt to acquire the loader lock.  If it did, the article would say so explicitly, or so I would hope.  [This blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/09/04/4731478.aspx) explains things more clearly than the article does, and the upshot is that there's no problem so long as you understand that the new thread won't actually start running until you've exited DllMain.

Comment: @Harry The document said *"it's risky"* even in the case of no synchronization. I'd call that explicit, even if it not very specific. I don't know of a particular reason either. Possibly something like the evil kernel-twin of the [AppInit_DLLs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/12/13/6648400.aspx) madness.

Comment: Well, I still can't really see reason why it's risky. Okay, I understand that it pauses the main exe, and waits until the finish of a DLLMain. I can't see any reason why CreateThread can stop the whole process.

I'm not stubborn, I just can't see any reason which is not "because that said that".

Comment: `TerminateThread()` will not release memory inside that thread either. Objects are not destroyed. So... don't use `TerminateThread()` for exiting a Thread!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest having your DLL spawn its own worker thread that can then use `WaitForSingleObject()` on the handle of the thread that you need to monitor.  The handle is signaled when the thread terminated, even when terminated by `TerminateThread()`.  Better would be to use `WaitForMultipleObjects()` so that your DLL can signal the worker thread when it needs to terminate, such as with `CreateEvent()` and `SetEvent()`.  That way the worker thread does not need to run a busy loop looking for a termination condition periodically.

Comment: Thank you, but let me explain a litte bit:
It would be for a kind of self defense, where those threads are really important and shouldn't be closed. In case of termination I would like to exit the whole process.

By making another thread helps nothing. They can easily Terminate all the threads at near the same time (I mean all threads which has been started by the specific DLL)

That's why I want some kind of callback which can't be terminated so easily.

Comment: And how do you think an app will identify which threads belong to your DLL and which belong to other modules, or even the OS? Threads running in the same process have no concept of which modules create them. The only way an app could safely single out your DLL's threads is to hook into `CreateThread()` itself and look at the return address on the call stack to see if it falls within the address space used by your DLL.

Comment: Yes, most peope say this because they just learnt it this way. Okay, I don't say that there is a 120% sure method to get, but with some "hack" you can detect which module started the thread.

The problem starts when someone is Manual mapping a module or hide it somehow, but I will find a way to detect it :)

So, all in one: it's possible & not that hard to find out which module started the thread (you have to look into PE structure & offsets).

Comment: You could obfuscate your monitoring code (or perhaps even your main code) by using the thread pool.  If the application also uses the thread pool, either directly or indirectly, the DLL code would be sharing the same threads as the application.

Answer (score 0):

I just readed documentation about [DllMain()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> If you terminate a thread by calling TerminateThread, the DLLs of that
>   thread do not receive DLL_THREAD_DETACH notifications.

So, in case thread termanatin you will not receive DLL_THREAD_DETACH.
The important think about DLL_THREAD_DETACH is that you will receive this notification in case "A thread is exiting cleanly"

Comment: If you really need to have notification about TerminateThread() then you need intercept this system call (with using GetModuleFileName() if needd) and so on

Comment: I see your point, but I want to get notification if the thread doesn't exit cleanly. This way the DllMain solution is not working.

Comment: If thread doesn't exit cleanly, you can't get notification via DllMain(). And there is no way to make DllMain() notifications work in some other way

Comment: I don't care if I don't use DllMain. I just mentioned that, I tried that. I'm open to use any other method, the only thing is important is the "end", to get notified if it has been terminated not cleanly. (Maybe a callback somehow?)

Comment: No, the only solution is catch system call to TerminateThread()

Comment: Well, but to achieve that I need a Global Hook, which is not that reliable ( injecting a DLL to each process? Quite easy to defeat :/ )

Maybe a ring0 can do such thing, but that would be pain in the a** to do :) /x64 reqires digital signature/ and it would look like a kind of malware, which I don't want.

Comment: No need for digital signature on x64. Anyway, you should add a requirement to your question that you want both 1. to be able to detect this, and 2. for it to be really simple to do so.

Answer (score -1):

You could run a watcher thread which will monitor all the threads you need and generate "no-more-the-thread" notifications.

Comment: Thank you, but let me explain a litte bit:
It would be for a kind of self defense, where those threads are really important and shouldn't be closed. In case of termination I would like to exit the whole process.

By making another thread helps nothing. They can easily Terminate all the threads at near the same time (I mean all threads which has been started by the specific DLL)

That's why I want some kind of callback which can't be terminated so easily.