# Can address space be recycled for multiple calls to MapViewOfFileEx without chance of failure?

Tags: windows, winapi, locking, shared-memory

Consider a complex, memory hungry, multi threaded application running within a 32bit address space on windows XP.

Certain operations require n large buffers of fixed size, where only one buffer needs to be accessed at a time.

The application uses a pattern where some address space the size of one buffer is reserved early and is used to contain the currently needed buffer.

This follows the sequence:
(initial run) VirtualAlloc -> VirtualFree -> MapViewOfFileEx 
(buffer changes) UnMapViewOfFile -> MapViewOfFileEx

Here the pointer to the buffer location is provided by the call to VirtualAlloc and then that same location is used on each call to MapViewOfFileEx.

The problem is that windows does not (as far as I know) provide any handshake type operation for passing the memory space between the different users.

Therefore there is a small opportunity (at each -> in my above sequence) where the memory is not locked and another thread can jump in and perform an allocation within the buffer.

The next call to MapViewOfFileEx is broken and the system can no longer guarantee that there will be a big enough space in the address space for a buffer.

Obviously refactoring to use smaller buffers reduces the rate of failures to reallocate space.

Some use of HeapLock has had some success but this still has issues - something still manages to steal some memory from within the address space.
(We tried Calling GetProcessHeaps then using HeapLock to lock all of the heaps)

What I'd like to know is there anyway to lock a specific block of address space that is compatible with MapViewOfFileEx?

Edit: I should add that ultimately this code lives in a library that gets called by an application outside of my control

Comment: And why do you call VirtualFree before MapViewOfFileEx?

Comment: Is there some reason you do not use a mutex for the whole memory block or a list of mutexs for predefined address spaces within that initially allocated memory?

Comment: Ah I think I understand. You want to optimize MapViewOfFileEx behind its back by guaranteeing the same heap block is always free.

Comment: Sebastian: yes - where optimize actually means guarantee success in environment where contiguous address space is unlikely to last out in the open

Comment: Noctis:how would that help? - I can't mutex every allocation made by any code in the process

Comment: So you're saying you UnMapViewOfFile() then try to map again at the same address?

Comment: Oh stupid Microsoft. They have all the necessary interface for implementing it, but don't have the implementation...

Answer (score 1):

You could brute force it; suspend every thread in the process that isn't the one performing the mapping, Unmap/Remap, unsuspend the suspended threads. It ain't elegant, but it's the only way I can think of off-hand to provide the kind of mutual exclusion you need.

Comment: Enumerate all threads: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686780(VS.85).aspx

Since there's a race (a thread could spawn another thread after you take the snapshot but before you suspend it) you will need to repeat the process until each snapshot identifies no further threads.

From the snapshot (which gives you thread IDs) you can OpenThread each thread to get a handle, and then call SuspendThread on that handle.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion but I worry this is a hack for hack replacement - I've realised the original problem is also open to VirtualAllocEx calls from another process.  I believe the API is not going to help me out.

Comment: I meant to add that, yes, you could get memory allocated by another process. But this is an uncommon event, to say the least. I suppose the real point is: there's no way within the API to do this (at least, not that I know of), so just how hard do you want to try to prevent it? The mechanism I suggested will at least stop the common case (a thread within the process performing an allocation that uses the block you need), which strikes me as "good enough", but your needs may differ.

Comment: I understand - my hope had been that I had overlooked a rigorous solution - it'll take some more thought to decid the best way forward

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at creating your own private heap via [`HeapCreate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366599%28VS.85%29.aspx)? You could set the heap to your desired buffer size. The only remaining problem is then how to get `MapViewOfFile`to use your private heap instead of the default heap.

I'd assume that `MapViewOfFile` internally calls `GetProcessHeap` to get the default heap and then it requests a contiguous block of memory. You can surround the call to `MapViewOfFile` with a detour, i.e., you rewire the `GetProcessHeap` call by overwriting the method in memory effectively inserting a jump to your own code which can return your private heap.

Microsoft has published the [Detour Library](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/) that I'm not directly familiar with however. I know that detouring is surprisingly common. Security software, virus scanners etc all use such frameworks. It's not pretty, but may work:

```
HANDLE g_hndPrivateHeap;

HANDLE WINAPI GetProcessHeapImpl() {
    return g_hndPrivateHeap;
}    


struct SDetourGetProcessHeap { // object for exception safety 
   SDetourGetProcessHeap() {
       // put detour in place
   }

   ~SDetourGetProcessHeap() {
       // remove detour again
   }
};


void MapFile() {
    g_hndPrivateHeap = HeapCreate( ... );

    {
        SDetourGetProcessHeap d;
        MapViewOfFile(...);
    }
}
```

These may also help:

[How to replace WinAPI functions calls in the MS VC++ project with my own implementation (name and parameters set are the same)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60641/how-to-replace-winapi-functions-calls-in-the-ms-vc-project-with-my-own-implemen)

[How can I hook Windows functions in C/C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/873658/how-can-i-hook-windows-functions-in-c-c)

http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/68568/huntusenixnt99.pdf

Comment: What i would like is to reserve (but not commit) the address space in the same manner as VirtualAlloc can but to then safely hand it over to MapViewOfFileEx

Comment: OK, you don't actually need the performance benefit of having an in-memory buffer, you only want to guarantee the memory is available.

Comment: I see where you're coming from - but this may well be a leap too far -> I'm guessing I hadn't overlooked anything obvious:)

Answer (score 0):

Imagine if I came to you with a piece of code like this:

```
void *foo;

foo = malloc(n);
if (foo)
   free(foo);
foo = malloc(n);
```

Then I came to you and said, help!  `foo` does not have the same address on the second allocation!

I'd be crazy, right?

It seems to me like you've already demonstrated clear knowledge of why this doesn't work.  There's a reason that the documention for any API that takes an explicit address to map into lets you know that the address is just a suggestion, and it can't be guaranteed.  This also goes for `mmap()` on POSIX.

I would suggest you write the program in such a way that a change in address doesn't matter.  That is, don't store too many pointers to quantities inside the buffer, or if you do, patch them up after reallocation. Similar to the way you'd treat a buffer that you were going to pass into `realloc()`.

Even the documentation for [`MapViewOfFileEx()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366763(VS.85).aspx) explicitly suggests this:

> While it is possible to specify an address that is safe now (not used by the operating system), there is no guarantee that the address will remain safe over time. Therefore, it is better to let the operating system choose the address. In this case, you would not store pointers in the memory mapped file, you would store offsets from the base of the file mapping so that the mapping can be used at any address.

**Update from your comments**

In that case, I suppose you could:

- Not map into contiguous blocks.  Perhaps you could map in chunks and write some intermediate function to decide which to read from/write to?
- Try porting to 64 bit.

Comment: Unfortunately the value of the pointer is not the problem - the problem is guaranteeing a large enough hole in the  address space.  Easy at startup hard later on.

Comment: I'd also add I'm supporting a mature system rather than designing a new one.

Comment: Unfortunately 32bit support will be required for a while yet - I agree the refactor is a possibility (I hinted at it in my question) - I was hoping this question might discover an alternative - thanks for the second opinion, much appreciated.

Comment: -1 for the malloc analogy. malloc is much higher level interface. On the system level the address space and the physical memory are separate. WinAPI gives you the ability to *reserve* an address space and then *allocate* (commit) a physical memory that is addressed by this region. MapViewOfFileEx was intended to allow exactly this, unfortunately it looks like the employee that started implementing it was fired before she finished, leaving us with yet another completely useless function...

Comment: @ybungalobill - "On the system level the address space and the physical memory are separate" -- when did I suggest otherwise?  I think you should chill out and re-read what I say, because the analogy holds. Expecting to reserve a chunk of address space and resize it without moving is extremely silly because something unrelated going on in your process might end up using the virtual address you end up requesting later. Especially re-read my quote from MSDN. This approach is asking for pain. To use another analogy to `malloc`, it's like using `realloc(p, n)` and assuming it always returns `p`.

Comment: @asveikau: neither me nor the OP want to resize the reserved region, we want just to remap the view to another view of the same size. [So how does the analogy holds exactly](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ArgumentByAnalogy)? A better analogy would be a placement `new` in C++: `T* newAddr = new(addr) T; assert(newAddr == addr);` And yes, I read the MSDN page even before I came here, what it effectively says is that the `MapViewOfFileEx` is useless.

Comment: @ybungalobill OK, but I parse what you are saying as essentially the same thing.  Or at least, the principal reason you can't do it is the same.  You can't rely on what unrelated things in your process are doing that might conflict with you.

Comment: @ybungalobill Also, it's not the API's fault if you're using it to do something stupid.  Let's say you're the implementation of `MapViewOfFileEx` and you're modifying page tables, but the caller's address range includes an entry that is already in use.  What do you do?  The obvious answer is to fail the call.  From that perspective the answer to this question is self evident.

Comment: @ybungalobill Lastly, as I re-read what was written, the `malloc` analogy holds.  `UnMapViewOfFile` effectively tells the system to release the page table entries, making it analogous to `free`.  Therefore any other caller can now reclaim that address space before your next call to `MapViewOfFileEx`.  The placement `new` analogy does not hold because there is never anything releasing the buffer in the middle.

Comment: @asveikau you seem to be helpfully explaining why it can't be done with the current API but maybe slightly missing what was being asked.  I think the placement new analogy is in the right direction.  I was hoping for an API that allowed MapViewOfFileEx to be called again for the same address and length without UnMapViewOfFile ever telling the system it was OK to take the address space back.

Comment: @morechilli Sorry to make you witness to all the flaming.  I don't think it's possible to do what you are asking.

Comment: @asveikau I came to the same conclusion unfortunately, all help and discussion much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As the earlier post suggests, you can suspend every thread in the process while you change the memory mappings.  You can use SuspendThread()/ResumeThread() for that.  This has the disadvantage that your code has to know about all the other threads and hold thread handles for them.

An alternative is to use the [Windows debug API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679295(v=vs.85).aspx) to suspend all threads.  If a process has a debugger attached, then every time the process faults, Windows will suspend all of the process's threads until the debugger handles the fault and resumes the process.

Also see this question which is very similar, but phrased differently:
[Replacing memory mappings atomically on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9052047/replacing-memory-mappings-atomically-on-windows)

Comment: Thanks for the cross link and suggestions.  Thankfully we have finally been allowed by our customer to phase out 32 bit support (for new work) so our address restrictions are less important - but the missing API functionality still frustrates me and remains a legacy issue.