# Replacing memory mappings atomically on Windows

Tags: windows, winapi, concurrency, shared-memory, atomic

Is there any way to atomically replace a memory mapping on Windows?

On Unix, mmap() with MAP_FIXED will atomically replace the page mapped at the requested address.

But on Windows, MapViewOfFileEx() can't be used on an address if a page is already mapped there.  The existing page must first be unmapped, e.g. with UnmapViewOfFile().  This means there is a short period during which the address is unallocated, so if another thread creates a memory mapping concurrently it might be placed at this address.

Is there an interface in Windows that gets around this problem, without modifying the kernel?  Perhaps using system calls directly?

Comment: This can't be a real problem, threads need to negotiate access to a shared resource.  Like mapped memory.  A named mutex is always required.

Comment: It's a real problem for sandboxing systems like Native Client (NaCl).  NaCl needs to reserve a chunk of address space which sandboxed code will be able to access.

Sometimes we want to modify the memory mappings in the sandbox's range of address space.  If we temporarily create a hole in that range and a non-sandboxed thread accidentally creates a mapping inside that hole, the sandboxed code could mess with the non-sandboxed thread.

Comment: @Mark: couldn't you protect all mapping operations with a mutex or critical section?

Comment: @Harry: No, we can't put a mutex around all mapping operations because we don't control all the code that runs inside our process.  System libraries might have threads running that allocate memory.  Injected DLLs (e.g. those used in virus checkers) might create threads that allocate memory.

Comment: Ordinary memory allocation (malloc, HeapAlloc, etc.) only takes place within already-allocated virtual address spaces.  System threads and injected DLLs are unlikely to mess with your address space, IMO, provided at least that you're reasonably circumspect about which APIs you use.  You can further reduce the risk by leaving a gap in the allocated virtual address space before your special address block, since address space is usually allocated from the bottom up.

Comment: So, assuming that there is no way to atomically remap the view (and I'm willing to bet that there isn't) it should be safe enough to go ahead and unmap and remap the view, perhaps using a high-priority thread as an additional precaution.  If the remapping fails, you can always relocate your address block; sure, that will take a relatively long time, but you aren't going to need to do it often.

Comment: I have also struggled with this issue - particularly in 32bit where keeping hold of a large single block of address space was important. I asked a similar question here [Can address space be recycled for multiple calls to MapViewOfFileEx without chance of failure?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1770115/5427)

Comment: The mentioned problem with Native Client confirms once more my opinion on Native Client (which is that even thinking about running native code downloaded from "somewhere on the web" in a browser window is an immensely stupid thing to do in the first place, for no substantial gain). As if JavaScript, Java, and Flash were not bad enough already.

Comment: Anyway, try [NtCreateSection](http://undocumented.ntinternals.net/UserMode/Undocumented%20Functions/NT%20Objects/Section/NtCreateSection.html) instead of `CreateFileMapping` and [NtMapViewOfSection](http://undocumented.ntinternals.net/UserMode/Undocumented%20Functions/NT%20Objects/Section/NtMapViewOfSection.html) instead of `MapViewOfFileEx`. No guarantees, but if you are lucky, the is-already-mapped condition is checked in the Win32 API, not in the kernel (sometimes there are silly restrictions in the API that the Nt functions don't have at all).

Comment: Looks like the "undocumented" Nt/Zw functions are documented in the mean time too: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff566428%28v=vs.85%29.aspx