# Mapping of several big files into memory

Tags: c++, windows-xp

In our application we have to be able to map several (i.e. maybe up to 4) files into memory (via *mapViewOfFile*). For a long time this has not been a problem, but as the files were getting bigger and bigger over the last years, now memory fragmentation prevents us from mapping those big files (files will be about 200 MB). The problem may already exist if no other files are loaded at that moment.

I am now looking for a way t make sure that the mapping is always successful. Therefor I wanted to reserve a block of memory at program start only for the mapping and that would therefor suffer much less from the fragmentation.

My first approach was to *HeapCreate* a private heap, I would then *HeapAlloc* a block of memory large enough to hold the mapping for one file and then use *MapViewOfFileEx* with the address of that block. Of cause the address would have to match the memory allocation granularity. But the mapping still failed with error code ERROR_INVALID_ADDRESS (487).

Next I tried the same thing with *VirtualAloc*. My understanding was that when I pass the parameter MEM_RESERVE I would then be able to use that memory for what ever I wanted, e.g. to map a view of a file. But I found out that that is not possible (same error code as above) until i completely free the whole block with *VirtualFree* again. Therefor there would be no reserved memory for the next files anymore.

I'm already using the *low fragmentation heap* feature and it is of nearly no use to us. Rewriting our code to use only smaller views of the files is not an option at the moment. I also took a look at this post [Can address space be recycled for multiple calls to MapViewOfFileEx without chance of failure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770115/can-address-space-be-recycled-for-multiple-calls-to-mapviewoffileex-without-chan) but didn't find any it very useful and was hoping for an other possibility.

Do you have any suggestions what I can do or where my design may be wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: By far the easiest solution is to use 64 bits addressing.

Comment: @MSalters That would certainly help, but it would mean a lot more work than a solution that would only require to write a few new functions for a correct memory allocation. Plus our customers all use 32 bit. But thanks anyway.

Comment: MMFs get over-used in Windows.  It already has a very good memory-mapped view of a file through the file system cache.  I can't tell your usage pattern, but *do* try to use just ReadFile/SetFilePointer and see if you really have a slowdown.

Comment: @HansPassant atm each piece of code gets it's own pointer into the mapping, to the position that belongs to the corresponding object. And those pointers are used just like that: pointers to some memory. So would have to write some access api first. But then again I might have to do that anyways.

Comment: So these pointers are like small views on the entire file mapping?  Problem solved.

Comment: @HansPassant That is a really good idea. Our framework might support this with only some small changes necessary. I will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the documentation for `MapViewOfFileEx` is clear: "The suggested address is used to specify that a file should be mapped at the same address in multiple processes. This requires the region of address space to be available in all involved processes. No other memory allocation can take place in the region that is used for mapping, including the use of the `VirtualAlloc`"

The low fragmentation heap is intended to prevent even relatively small allocations from failing. I.e. it avoids 1 byte holes so 2 byte allocations will remain possible for longer. Your allocations are not small by 32 bits standards.

Realistically, this is going to hurt. If you really really need it, reimplement memory mapped files. All the necessary functions are available. Use a vectored exception handler to page in the source, and use `QueryWorkingSet` to figure out if pages are dirty.

Comment: I knew that `MapViewOfFileEx` could be used to share memory between processes, but I wasn't aware that it is intended to. Reimplementing memory mapped files really will hurt, as by now I have no idea how it is done at all. I might have to look into that.