# How to reserve memory on Windows and later map files into it?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, memory-mapping

I would like to reserve a region of memory and later map files contiguously into the reserved memory. There may be large time gaps between mapping the files during which other functions may allocate memory from the heap. Once mapped, a file may not be unmapped and mapped to a new memory location.

On Linux that would be something like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <cerrno>

int main(){
    void *memory = mmap(nullptr, getpagesize() * 2,
                        PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_NORESERVE, -1, 0); // reserve memory
    int handle1 = ::open("1", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, S_IRWXU); // open file1
    int handle2 = ::open("2", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, S_IRWXU); // open file2
    void *data = mmap(memory, getpagesize(), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED |MAP_FIXED, handle1, 0); // map first file into reserved memory
    void *data2 = mmap(static_cast<char *>(memory) + getpagesize(), getpagesize(), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_FIXED, handle2, 0); // map second file into reserved memory
}
```

On Windows however I can't seem to find the correct way to do this. Does anyone know how this is done?

Edit:
Since the my goal seems to be not that easy to understand. Once again simplified:

I would like to have memory that is memory mapped. Once the mapped memory is filled with data I would like to map a new file into memory directly after the already mapped memory to extend the mapped memory (without leaving a gap between the two memory mapped regions).

At a later program start the files may be used to restore all the data of the previous run.

Problem with solution with sparse files and extending existing file:
Program should be able to remove files if they aren't needed any more. Therefore its important that the mappings are always new files.

You may think of it more as an allocator. Memory mapped memory is needed. The library maps a block of memory and returns a pointer to a subblock. The memory is no longer needed, it is returned to the allocator. In case an entire mapping is no longer needed, the associated file is removed (The data does not need to be written by the mapping if it is no longer needed).

Comment: google "windows memory mapped file"

Comment: Its not about mapping a file, thats easy. Its about mapping a file into memory that was previously reserved so I can map different files into contiguous memory

Comment: @johnST - on windows this is impossible - if you try map file to reserved memory you got error `STATUS_CONFLICTING_ADDRESSES`

Comment: Are you sure that this can't be done at all?

Comment: @johnST - yes, I sure, but don't know are this can be proved

Comment: already was close question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10291864/mapping-of-several-big-files-into-memory

Comment: that question is not about mapping files contiguously, its about making sure all files are mapped without an error

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. Maybe you should ask about the real problem you are trying to solve, rather than how to implement your solution.

Comment: @johnST - "In case I run out of memory mapped memory" - this is how ? "map a new file into memory directly after the already mapped memory" - how the new file related to already mapped ? you want *extend* mapped file ?

Comment: @johnST - "Once the mapped memory is filled " - section must be backed by real file on disk, or can me only memory mapped (page-file backed sections ) ?

Comment: @johnST - now understand. really exist exact solution for your problem, but for this need use NT api (win32 not enough here) - if want i can post it (20 min~), but many will be not happy by NT used

Comment: It's not your goal, that needed additional explanation. It is your overall problem you are trying to solve, that we don't know much about. If you explain what you are ultimately trying to accomplish, we can make better recommendations.

Comment: It might still be possible to use a sparse file.  When content is no longer needed, you can re-zero it with FSCTL_SET_ZERO_DATA.  (Except that I'm not 100% sure this will work as desired on memory mapped files.)  If you're dealing with a lot of data, you might run into the maximum file size limit, I guess.

Comment: Failing that, you're probably going to have to bite the bullet and redesign your algorithm.

Comment: not redesign, the library will just have to keep the fallback implementation that translates virtual to actual addresses using a map of file mappings and virtual addresses

Comment: Ah, so your problem is already solved. :-)  That makes it easy.

Comment: yes =) but would have been nice to remove that slow alternative, on the linux side it is just reserved_address_start + vaddress, way more efficient

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need to have it reserved when you map in the files, you just need to know that you can map in the two files contiguously somewhere. For example your Linux example code, being single threaded, would work just as well if you immediately unmapped the reserved region before mapping in the files.

On Windows, handling the possible multithreaded race condition, you can do something like:

```
 while(1) {
     char *memory = VirtualAlloc(NULL, page_size * 2, MEM_RESERVE, 0);
     VirtualFree(memory);
     if (MapViewOfFileEx(handle1, FILE_MAP_WRITE, 0, 0, page_size, memory) == NULL
         && GetLastError() == ERROR_INVALID_ADDRESS) {
         continue;
     }
     if (MapViewOfFileEx(handle2, FILE_MAP_WRITE, 0, 0, page_size, memory + page_size) == NULL
         && GetLastError() == ERROR_INVALID_ADDRESS) {
         UnMapViewOfFile(memory);
         continue;
     }
     break;
}
```

Comment: This is just a minimal example. The files won't be mapped immediately after each other. There are large time gaps in between during which other functions may allocate memory from the heap

Comment: @johnST That's not fundamentally a problem here, you just have to pick another address when you detect a conflict, but I'm guessing there's other details your leaving out

Comment: once mapped a file may not be unmapped

Comment: @RossRidge - sorry for `STATUS_CONFLICTING_ADDRESSES` (i think you copy/paste it from my comment) - really this error returned by `ZwMapViewOfSection`. `MapViewOfFileEx` (which is thin shell over Zw*) convert it to `ERROR_INVALID_ADDRESS` - so `GetLastError() == ERROR_INVALID_ADDRESS` must be in code

Comment: @RbMm Yah, the documentation for MapViewOfFileEx doesn't say what error code is in this case, so I just took the value from your comment. I should've added a note that effect in my answer.

Comment: `MapViewOfFileEx` is thin shell over `ZwMapViewOfSection`. error returned from NT is converted by `RtlNtStatusToDosError`. errors here can be very different, but in case conflicting address NT error is `STATUS_CONFLICTING_ADDRESSES` which converted to `ERROR_INVALID_ADDRESS`

Comment: One nitpick: I believe you'll need to align to the allocation granularity (64KB IIRC) rather than the page size (usually 4KB).

Comment: @HarryJohnston Ah, good point.  Yah, the second MapViewOfFileEx call will fail if `page_size` isn't the allocation granularity.

Answer (score 2):

my solution used **UNDOCUMENTED** api

```
NTSYSAPI NTSTATUS NTAPI ZwExtendSection ( HANDLE SectionHaqndle, PLARGE_INTEGER SectionSize );
```

no win32 analog for this function, but this is key point of solution.
also we need use [`ZwMapViewOfSection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff566481(v=vs.85).aspx) but not [`MapViewOfFileEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366763(v=vs.85).aspx) (win32 shell over [`ZwMapViewOfSection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff566481(v=vs.85).aspx)) because [`MapViewOfFileEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366763(v=vs.85).aspx)  have less parameters than [`ZwMapViewOfSection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff566481(v=vs.85).aspx) - we cannot set `ULONG AllocationType` to `MEM_RESERVE` - but this is also key point. for other tasks we can use win32 analog, but for uniformity and style i will be use NT api.

*of course many just say that it undocumented, unsupported, etc use ntdll api direct - but really it work and here i not view solution based on win32 only. so who want can use, who not want can not use. as is*

the idea - we just reserve required large region with call to [`ZwMapViewOfSection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff566481(v=vs.85).aspx) (this is impossible done by [`MapViewOfFileEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366763(v=vs.85).aspx)) and then, when need we can extent this region by call to `ZwExtendSection`

solution tested and worked.

```
class SECTION_EX
{
    LARGE_INTEGER _CurrentSize, _MaximumSize;
    HANDLE _hSection;
    PVOID _BaseAdress;

public:
    NTSTATUS Create(POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES poa, SIZE_T InitialSize, SIZE_T MaximumSize);
    NTSTATUS Extend(SIZE_T NewSize);

    SECTION_EX()
    {
        _BaseAdress = 0;
        _hSection = 0;
    }

    ~SECTION_EX()
    {
        if (_hSection) 
        {
            if (_BaseAdress) ZwUnmapViewOfSection(NtCurrentProcess(), _BaseAdress);
            ZwClose(_hSection);
        }
    }
};

NTSTATUS SECTION_EX::Extend(SIZE_T NewSize)
{
    LARGE_INTEGER Size;
    Size.QuadPart = NewSize; 

    if (Size.QuadPart <= _CurrentSize.QuadPart)
    {
        return STATUS_SUCCESS;
    }

    if (Size.QuadPart > _MaximumSize.QuadPart)
    {
        return STATUS_SECTION_TOO_BIG;
    }

    NTSTATUS status = ZwExtendSection(_hSection, &Size);

    if (0 <= status)
    {
        _CurrentSize = Size;
    }

    return status;
}

NTSTATUS SECTION_EX::Create(POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES poa, SIZE_T InitialSize, SIZE_T MaximumSize)
{
    HANDLE hFile;
    IO_STATUS_BLOCK iosb;

    NTSTATUS status = ZwCreateFile(&hFile, FILE_GENERIC_READ|FILE_GENERIC_WRITE, poa,
        &iosb, 0, 0, FILE_SHARE_VALID_FLAGS, FILE_OPEN_IF, FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_ALERT, 0, 0);

    if (0 <= status)
    {
        _MaximumSize.QuadPart = MaximumSize;

        LARGE_INTEGER Size, *pSize = &Size;
        Size.QuadPart = InitialSize;

        if (iosb.Information == FILE_OPENED)
        {
            FILE_STANDARD_INFORMATION fsi;

            if (0 <= (status = ZwQueryInformationFile(hFile, &iosb, &fsi, sizeof(fsi), FileStandardInformation)))
            {
                if (fsi.EndOfFile.QuadPart)
                {
                    pSize = 0;// in case file already exist with not zero size - use it
                }
            }
        }

        if (0 <= status)
        {
            status = ZwCreateSection(&_hSection, SECTION_ALL_ACCESS, 0, pSize, 
                PAGE_READWRITE, SEC_COMMIT, hFile);
        }

        ZwClose(hFile);

        if (0 <= status)
        {
            SECTION_BASIC_INFORMATION sbi;

            if (0 <= ZwQuerySection(_hSection, SectionBasicInformation, &sbi, sizeof(sbi), 0))
            {
                _CurrentSize = sbi.Size;// real file size in bytes, without align

                // !!! use MEM_RESERVE !!!
                // MaximumSize - will be reserved, but not all commited

                status = ZwMapViewOfSection(_hSection, NtCurrentProcess(), &_BaseAdress, 0, 
                    0, 0, &MaximumSize, ViewUnmap, MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);
            }
        }
    }

    return status;
}

void demoS()
{
    SECTION_EX se;
    STATIC_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES(oa, "\\??\\c:\\***");
    // reserve 256Mb,but initially commit only 32kb or file size
    if (0 <= se.Create(&oa, 0x8000, 0x10000000))
    {
        se.Extend(0x18000);
        se.Extend(0x1e245);
        se.Extend(0x74100);
    }
}
```

---

update: i discover that begin from win 8.1 we can reserve memory region with section by used also *undocumented* `FILE_MAP_RESERVE` - so need call

```
_BaseAdress = MapViewOfFileEx(_hSection, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS|FILE_MAP_RESERVE, 0, 0, MaximumSize, 0);
```

but in windows 7 , vista and XP - this will be not work. however `ZwMapViewOfSection` worked with `MEM_RESERVE` flag even in XP.

so usual situation - frequently win32 shell have less functional compare corresponded Nt*/Zw* function.

and still no any win32 analog/shell for `ZwExtendSection` (this call extend both file and view)

Comment: That only extends the existing mapping, doesn't it?  I believe the OP wants to create a new mapping - a different file - adjacent to the existing one.

Comment: @HarryJohnston - really call to ZwExtendSection extend both - file and mapping in single call. and this is really worked! i already use it - need reserve memory for (potential) huge data-base and add records to it - so reserve (but not map) big memory region. when adding new record require extend - i extend section - view and file etended

Comment: Oh, I think I see what you mean - the OP might not really need to map multiple files if it is possible to extend the original file instead.  Yes, that makes sense.

Comment: @HarryJohnston - yes, this is higly undocumented, but it really perfect worked - extendable file and map with reserved region. i have no sense to lie - i just test all this code - all worked. i think you also if want can test( your level let you do this)

Comment: @HarryJohnston - yes, at begin i also not understand what really OP need and think that task impossible, but after several question, OP modify question - i understand that really solution exist, i even exactly implement this kind of DB some time ago - so take almost ready code

Answer (score 1):

The correct solution is to rearchitecture to eliminate the requirement for adjacent mappings.

Depending on your exact needs, one approach would be to use a single sparse file ([as described here](https://ayende.com/blog/163137/sparse-files-memory-mapped-files)) whose initial length is equal to the amount of address space you want to reserve.  Because the file is sparse, only the blocks that are actually used take up space on disk.

Failing that, you may need to change the underlying algorithms that are processing the data so that they no longer depend on the memory being contiguous.  This usually isn't as hard as it may sound.

---

One (not at all proper!) alternative would be to hook the VirtualAlloc function so that you can make it block as necessary.  That would allow you to manipulate your reserved memory range in an effectively atomic manner - you can free it, map part of it, and then re-reserve the rest, similar to Ross Ridge's answer, without any concern that another thread will allocate the memory while you are doing so.

(That wouldn't protect you from device drivers, but AFAIK it is extremely rare for a device driver to spontaneously allocate memory in user address space.)

*NB:* I'm assuming here that using a single file isn't acceptable for some reason.  If a single file will do, you should use a sparse file as suggested above.  If for some reason a single file will do but using a sparse file isn't an option, I would recommend RbMm's approach over this one - neither is a *good* solution, but my best guess is that this one is marginally more risky.  (It is certainly more difficult.)

Comment: only honesty - you believe that all this better (even "hook the VirtualAlloc" ,etc) than use native solution which require ntdll api usage ? or you not believe that my code really worked as required ? i really want to understand and interesting. sorry for asking

Comment: @RbMm: your solution, if I understand correctly, depends on the assumption that having a single file (rather than multiple files) will be acceptable.  In that case, however, a sparse file can be used instead, avoiding the need to use the native API.  I only suggest hooking in case using a single file is not acceptable.  I'll rewrite to clarify that.  (I have absolutely no doubt that your solution will work, but I believe that using a sparse file would be safer and just as efficient.)

Comment: yes, this is solution for single file (OP several time change this in question - single/multiple). about sparse file - i check this next day (now late in my timezone) - you sure that when we map say 256mb sparse file- memory will be really reserved, but not committed just ? (however even if committed - no physical memory will be associated with this, until first access). interesting will be check - i never map sparse file in memory yet :)

Comment: @RbMm: I don't know whether the memory will technically be counted as committed or not, but it shouldn't really matter, just so long as it doesn't take up disk space.

Comment: yes, solution with sparsed files working. however all memory region (equal to file size) will be commit just. but this is not very big overhead. from another side we not need call `ZwExtendSection` here. when in my variant this need call yourself, some advantage here that most memory will reserved only and commited by request (`ZwExtendSection`)